# How to generate folder ownership lists for each user?

Tags: linux, files, find, users

I'd like to generate several separate lists for each user in Ubuntu. The lists contains the files and folders belong to each user.

Using the command following list me all the users in the system:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1;}'
```

Suppose "user1" is the first result, I'd like to get the list as:

```
find / -user "user1" > user1.txt
```

Thus, my problem is how can I get all the lists using commands as little as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | while read USER ; do
  echo $USER #use this to show some kind of progress otherwise delete this string
  find / -user $USER > ${USER}.txt 2>/dev/null
done
```

ps. for more information look at [shell loops](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html).

However it is pretty bad idea: you'll need to run `find` on the whole filesystem as many times as many users you have.

We will be much smarter and do it in another way: we will run `find` only once and split it's output to a files like this:

```
find / -printf "%u %p\n" | awk '{print $2 > $1".txt"}'
```

Comment: You'll need `>>` if you want more than the last file for each user.

Comment: @Kevin an awk redirection a quite differ from shells one. `>>` will append awk output to the existing files content, `>` will empty file and put the full output, not just last line. For details look at http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_38.html#SEC41

Comment: @rush That's really helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

At least GNU find has the `-fprint` variant, with that you can accomplish what you want with one pass of the filesystem using the idiom: `find path -user user1 -fprint user1.txt`.

First generate the `-user` and `-fprint` arguments:

```bash
findargs=""
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do
  if [[ -z $findargs ]]; then
    findargs="-user $user -fprint $user.txt";
  else 
    findargs="$findargs -or -user $user -fprint $user.txt"
  fi
done
```

You're now ready to parse the filesystem:

```
find path/to/parse $findargs
```